# Search again in SQL on another column if first search returns no results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm doing a simple search on a database and return results to a PHP file to display on screen.
I'm using the code below.

```
// CONNECT TO DATABASE
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]
  );
} catch (Exception $ex) { exit($ex->getMessage()); }

// SEARCH
// $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ? OR `AMKA_anchor_MEMBER` LIKE ?");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `teachers` WHERE `AMKA` LIKE ?");
// $stmt->execute(["%".$_POST['search']."%", "%".$_POST['search']."%"]);
$stmt->execute(["%".$_POST['search']."%"]);

//Empty Results? Need to search again for Anchored AMKA.
if ($stmt->rowCount() = 0) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `teachers` WHERE `AMKA_anchor_MEMBER` LIKE ?");
    $stmt->execute(["%".$_POST['search']."%"]);
}

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) { echo json_encode($results); }
```

I have an if statement there

> if ($stmt->rowCount() = 0) { ... etc etc

If I remove that statement the search works just fine. It gets the results and I get to display them on screen. But I want to make a second search if the first query returns empty, to check if the search string is found on another column (AMKA_anchor_MEMBER). When I try that, the whole search doesn't work. I need that to also display a special message like "users not found. Searching for immediate dependants" and then the results from the second query.

You will see that I tried the query using OR but that does not produce the message I want. Just results but no way to tell if they were made on the second go.

I'm stuck with that. Any ideas?

Comment: `$stmt->rowCount() = 0` should be `$stmt->rowCount() == 0`. You are trying to assign instead of comparing.

Comment: Why not use one query, with a Left join?

Comment: Well I made a query that checks like that:
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ? OR `AMKA_anchor_MEMBER` LIKE ?
But I want to find a way to get a message through when the match is on the second column.

Comment: You were both right and the left join actually gave me an idea to approach it differently. Thank you. I will post my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached it differently and decided to do the whole thing in the database and actually return 2 columns. Here is my solution:

```
// CONNECT TO DATABASE
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHARSET.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]
  );
} catch (Exception $ex) { exit($ex->getMessage()); }

// SEARCH
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT CONCAT(p.AMKA,', ',p.lastname,', ',p.name,', ',p.sullogos,', ',p.telephone,', ',p.school) AS 'Teacher' 
                        FROM teachers p 
                        WHERE p.AMKA LIKE ? 
                        AND p.AMKA_anchor_MEMBER LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%".$_POST['search']."%", "%".$_POST['search']."%"]);

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT CONCAT(p.AMKA,', ',p.lastname,', ',p.name) AS 'Person',
                            CONCAT('Συγγενής πρώτου βαθμού του: ',t.lastname,',',t.name,' με ΑΜΚΑ: ', t.AMKA,' Σχολείο: ',t.school) AS 'Teacher'
                            FROM teachers p
                            INNER JOIN teachers t ON p.AMKA_anchor_MEMBER = t.AMKA
                            WHERE p.AMKA LIKE ?
                            ORDER BY Person");
    $stmt->execute(["%".$_POST['search']."%"]);
}

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) { echo json_encode($results); }
```

I really missed the double equal sign at the if statement. Should have noticed that but thanks for pointing it out. Also ... Of course I should have used the inner join... I just needed a nudge to think about it.